# which browsers support digest authentication

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

which browsers support digest authentication? I guess Firefox, chrome and IE
What is digest authentication. How it is different from form authentication, passport authentication or windows authentication

Comment: What has your research shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most if not all browsers support digest authentication. Here are two links that might be a good starting point.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778868%28v=WS.10%29.aspx
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_digest.html

For difference between form and windows authentication:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388524/3199478